# Project fields from nested arrays of objects in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d302a6da9b1d6ae926c16a3"),
    "location" : "car",
    "playlist" : [ 
        {
            "playlist_number" : "1",
            "number_of_songs" : "100",
            "drive" : [ 
                {
                   "drive_number" : "13",
                    "drive_name" : "Ooms",
                    "songs" : [ 
                        "59 Volvo", 
                        "Yield Not To Temptation - Single Version", 
                        "Johnny Angel", 
                        "The Madison Time", 
                        "Little Brown Jug", 
                        "Only In My Dreams"
                    ]
                }, 
                 {
                   "drive_number" : "Z3",
                    "drive_name" : "codes",
                    "songs" : [ 
                        "59 Volvo", 
                        "Perfect", 
                        "Hands clap", 
                        "I Ran", 
                        "Falling down", 
                        "Sounds of middle earth"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There can be many other `location` as well that may contain variable number of `playlist` objects (which in turn can contain `n` number of `playlist_number`, you get the idea).

When I search for a song by name for eg: `59 Volvo` I should get back `location`, `playlist_number`, `drive_number` and `drive_name`. I tried with nested `$elemMatch` but it gives the whole document.